# ffmpeg 4.2.2 gives segmentation fault after a while

Tags: ffmpeg, crash, rtsp, rtmp, fault

I have compiled ffmpeg 4.2.2 and it gives me a segmatation fault after a while and i don't knw why, i put it the request and a part of the debug log file.
My ffmpeg request:
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel debug -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://root:My_PW@My_IP_Address:5541/live.sdp" -f image2 -loop 1 -i ./overlay_score_160.png -i ./partenaire.png -filter_complex 'overlay=x=2:y=1,overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=1' -framerate 25 -crf 18 -preset veryfast -g 50 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/stream1 -async 1 -vsync 1 2> debug.txt

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.2-eric-01022020-FF422 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --disable-static --enable-shared --disable-debug --enable-avresample --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-pthreads --enable-libfreetype --enable-filters --enable-openssl --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libxvid --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libspeex --extra-version=eric-01022020-FF422 --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg-4.2.2
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-use_wallclock_as_timestamps' ... matched as AVOption 'use_wallclock_as_timestamps' with argument '1'.
Reading option '-rtsp_transport' ... matched as AVOption 'rtsp_transport' with argument 'tcp'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'rtsp://root:MyPW@My_IP_Address:5541/live.sdp'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'image2'.
Reading option '-loop' ... matched as AVOption 'loop' with argument '1'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument './overlay_score_160.png'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument './partenaire.png'.
Reading option '-filter_complex' ... matched as option 'filter_complex' (create a complex filtergraph) with argument 'overlay=x=2:y=1,overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=1'.
Reading option '-framerate' ... matched as AVOption 'framerate' with argument '25'.
Reading option '-crf' ... matched as AVOption 'crf' with argument '18'.
Reading option '-preset' ... matched as AVOption 'preset' with argument 'veryfast'.
Reading option '-g' ... matched as AVOption 'g' with argument '50'.
Reading option '-vcodec' ... matched as option 'vcodec' (force video codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'libx264'.
Reading option '-acodec' ... matched as option 'acodec' (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'copy'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'flv'.
Reading option 'rtmp://localhost/hls/stream1' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-async' ... matched as option 'async' (audio sync method) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-vsync' ... matched as option 'vsync' (video sync method) with argument '1'.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Applying option filter_complex (create a complex filtergraph) with argument overlay=x=2:y=1,overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=1.
Applying option async (audio sync method) with argument 1.
Applying option vsync (video sync method) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url rtsp://root:MyPW@My_IP_Address:5541/live.sdp.
Successfully parsed a group of options.

........

[libx264 @ 0x55819256fc00] frame=24887 QP=17.51 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:80  I:53   P:783  SKIP:38   size=8835 bytes
[libx264 @ 0x55819256fc00] frame=24888 QP=21.08 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:76  I:0    P:219  SKIP:655  size=254 bytes
[h264 @ 0x5581925ca200] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
[image2 @ 0x558192485380] Opening './overlay_score_160.png' for reading
[file @ 0x7f32640080c0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x7f3264008140] Statistics: 1988 bytes read, 0 seeks
[Parsed_overlay_0 @ 0x5581927cbf00] n:20781.000000 t:831.281311 pos:nan x:2.000000 xi:2 y:1.000000 yi:0
[Parsed_overlay_1 @ 0x5581927cdf00] n:20781.000000 t:831.281311 pos:nan x:258.000000 xi:258 y:1.000000 yi:0
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.474174
[libx264 @ 0x55819256fc00] frame=24889 QP=22.84 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:74  I:0    P:7    SKIP:867  size=36 bytes
[h264 @ 0x5581925e68c0] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
[Parsed_overlay_0 @ 0x5581927cbf00] n:20782.000000 t:831.311122 pos:nan x:2.000000 xi:2 y:1.000000 yi:0
[Parsed_overlay_1 @ 0x5581927cdf00] n:20782.000000 t:831.311122 pos:nan x:258.000000 xi:258 y:1.000000 yi:0
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.580742
[libx264 @ 0x55819256fc00] frame=24890 QP=22.80 NAL=0 Slice:B Poc:78  I:0    P:190  SKIP:684  size=167 bytes
[h264 @ 0x558192603080] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
[image2 @ 0x558192485380] Opening './overlay_score_160.png' for reading
[file @ 0x7f3264007f80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x7f3264008300] Statistics: 1988 bytes read, 0 seeks
[Parsed_overlay_0 @ 0x5581927cbf00] n:20783.000000 t:831.351278 pos:nan x:2.000000 xi:2 y:1.000000 yi:0
[Parsed_overlay_1 @ 0x5581927cdf00] n:20783.000000 t:831.351278 pos:nan x:258.000000 xi:258 y:1.000000 yi:0
Clipping frame in rate conversion by 0.377281
[libx264 @ 0x55819256fc00] frame=24891 QP=17.17 NAL=2 Slice:P Poc:88  I:1    P:230  SKIP:643  size=806 bytes
frame=24917 fps= 30 q=24.0 size=   25410kB time=00:13:51.90 bitrate= 250.2kbits/s dup=6033 drop=1899 speed=   1x    ^M[h264 @ 0x55819261f840] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
[image2 @ 0x558192485380] Opening './overlay_score_160.png' for reading
[file @ 0x7f3264006d80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x7f32640080c0] Statistics: 1988 bytes read, 0 seeks
[Parsed_overlay_0 @ 0x5581927cbf00] n:20784.000000 t:831.372222 pos:nan x:2.000000 xi:2 y:1.000000 yi:0
[Parsed_overlay_1 @ 0x5581927cdf00] n:20784.000000 t:831.372222 pos:nan x:258.000000 xi:258 y:1.000000 yi:0
Past duration 0.749565 too large
[libx264 @ 0x55819256fc00] frame=24892 QP=18.73 NAL=2 Slice:B Poc:84  I:0    P:29   SKIP:845  size=80 bytes
[h264 @ 0x55819263c000] nal_unit_type: 1(Coded slice of a non-IDR picture), nal_ref_idc: 1
[image2 @ 0x558192485380] Opening './overlay_score_160.png' for reading
[file @ 0x7f3264007f80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x7f32640080c0] Statistics: 1988 bytes read, 0 seeks
[image2 @ 0x558192485380] Opening './overlay_score_160.png' for reading
[file @ 0x7f3264006d80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
[AVIOContext @ 0x7f32640080c0] Statistics: 1988 bytes read, 0 seeks
```

Then i get "Segmentation fault" and ffmpeg exits

Comment: I don't see any errors, but it appears some of the log was truncated. Do you get the seg fault if you output to a local file instead of network output? Does a build from the git master branch behave the same? [Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks for your help, i did not try from a local file but one thing is sure: from the time i use version 4 of ffmpeg, i lost the stream very often (tried several cameras, i stream live sports here from 8 years now). the two versions i use with these problems are 4.4.2 and 4.1.3. the bundled 3.4.(4/6) that came with APT-GET INSTALL in Ubuntu 18.04 does not loose connexions like version 4. i don't understand.

Comment: Try a recent version from git master branch and report back.

Comment: OK i will try the latest of .. latest. Come back to u.

Comment: hi. i've compiled ffmpeg from master branch, and wheni execute it i get: this error message  ./ffmpeg
./ffmpeg: relocation error: ./ffmpeg: symbol avio_print_string_array version LIBAVFORMAT_58 not defined in file libavformat.so.58 with link time reference

Comment: How did you try to compile ffmpeg? Try the download instead.

Comment: finally and because the version 4 i've been using are unstable i'm back to 3.4.6 and it's stable.

Comment: It would have been good to know if this occurs with a build from the git master branch. Then a bug report could have been filed.